# Cannot get interface information using read

Tags: shell-script, zsh, read

The following link has a script to get system information:

[z3bra' blog](http://blog.z3bra.org/2014/04/meeting-at-the-bar.html)

Specifically,

```
network() {

   read lo int1 int2 <<< `ip link | sed -n 's/^[0-9]: \(.*\):.*$/\1/p'`

   if iwconfig $int1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
       wifi=$int1
       eth0=$int2

   else
      wifi=$int2
      eth0=$int1

   fi

   ip link show $eth0 | grep 'state UP' >/dev/null && int=$eth0     ||int=$wifi

#int=eth0

    ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1 && 
        echo "$int connected" || echo "$int disconnected"
}
```

If I just execute:

`ip link | sed -n 's/^[0-9]: \(.*\):.*$/\1/p'`

I get a list of interfaces (as expected)

But if I execute

```
 read lo int1 int2 <<< `ip link | sed -n 's/^[0-9]: \(.*\):.*$/\1/p'`
```

I get nothing. When I check `$lo`, `$int1`, and `$int2`, there is still nothing. It's like read isn't working as intended.

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this? I do not understand enough about read to really know how to debug this.

Comment: Possible your bash version didn't understand `<<<` redirection.

Comment: What do you expect if you blindly copy dumb stuff you found on the web ? That code is quite ugly to say the least... The reason it works for him is because `bash` does word splitting on the part after `<<<` because it isn't quoted and that expands into a one-line string which isn't the case with `zsh`  as the output will be intact, e.g. one word per line (just replace the `read ...` before the `<<<` with `cat` and try it in both `bash` and `zsh` and you'll see the difference). Anyway the quick, dirty fix is to use `read -d '' lo int1 int2`.

Comment: I'd personally read the names into an array: `ifaces=("${(@f)$(ip -o link | awk -F': ' '{if ($2 !~ "lo") print $2}')}")`  and then use indexes e.g. `if iwconfig ${ifaces[1]}... wifi=${ifaces[1]}; eth0=${ifaces[2]}` etc...

Comment: @don_crissti I get the error "${(@f)$(ip -o link | awk -F': ' '{if ($2 !~ "lo") print $2}')}: bad substitution" when I run your code. The lecturing was unnecessary.

Comment: My code runs fine here (`zsh 5.0.7`).  Other than that, sorry for the "lecturing" part. Good luck !

Comment: @don_crissti Please post your read -d solution so  I can give you points for it. It's dirty, but it works until I fix the awk problem.

Comment: What's your `awk` version/flavor ? You can do it with `sed` too. Open a terminal and run: `ifaces=("${(@f)$(ip -o link | sed 's/^[0-9]*: \([^:]*\):.*/\1/')}")` to read the interfaces into an array. Or even shorter: `ifaces=("${(@f)$(ls /sys/class/net)}")` .You can then use indexes, e.g. `print ${ifaces[2]}` to print the second element (interface) etc... Try that and let me know if it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `for`-loop with array instead `read`:

```
for link in `ip link | sed -n 's/^[0-9]: \(.*\):.*$/\1/p'`
do
    int[${#int[*]}]=$link
done
```

So you'll receive `${int[1]}` and `${int[2]}`
If arrays do not supported by shell:

```
i=0
for link in `ip link | sed -n 's/^[0-9]: \(.*\):.*$/\1/p'`
do
    eval int$i=$link
    let i+=1
done
```

Comment: Seems to give me the same problem. No output at the end of the function.

Comment: If I echo $link it shows all of the available interfaces, so something is working at least.

Comment: Sorry to keep commenting like this, but also - I run ZSH, and ZSH supports triple redirection apparently.